# "‘Node’ is applied to too few arguments" even though there are exact number

Tags: haskell, syntax, function-call

`s` and `a` are type variables. 
In the constructor the first two param are the data, then its parent, its level in the graph and then a list of its children.

```
data Node s a = Root | Node s a (Node s a) Int [Node s a]
createRoot :: (ProblemState s a) => s-> a -> Node s a
createRoot state act= Node (state act Root 0 [])
```

And I've passed the exact same amount of 5 arguments to Node constructor, however I'm getting errors.

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Node s a’
              with actual type ‘a1
                                -> Node s1 a1 -> Int -> [Node s1 a1] -> Node s1 a1’
• Probable cause: ‘Node’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the expression: Node (state act Root 0 [])
  In an equation for ‘createRoot’:
      createRoot state act = Node (state act Root 0 [])
• Relevant bindings include
    act :: a (bound at Search.hs:43:24)
    state :: s (bound at Search.hs:43:18)
    createRoot :: s -> a -> Node s a (bound at Search.hs:43:1)
```

Comment: Looks just like a bracketing error to me. `Node (state act Root 0 [])` says you're giving the `Node` constructor 1 parameter, whose value as `state act Root 0 []`. I believe you meant the same with no parentheses: `Node state act Root 0 []`, which is how you apply 5 arguments to a function in Haskell.

Comment: Haskell functions are called `fun arg1 arg2 arg4`, not `fun (arg1 arg2 arg3)` — the latter is read like `fun(arg1(arg2, arg3))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parentheses are used for grouping expressions. `(length "hello" + 2)` is a single value, not 4.

Similarly, `Node (...)` applies `Node` to a single argument: `(state act Root 0 [])`. Obviously that's wrong (and would require `state` to be a function taking four arguments).

The solution is to just remove the parentheses:

```
Node state act Root 0 []
```

Now `Node` is applied to five arguments.